# Java Concurrency in Practice “Listing 7.9. Interrupting a task in a dedicated thread.”. What is the purpose of scheduled taskThread.interrupt()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice and encounter the following code snippet.

```
public static void timedRun(final Runnable r,
                            long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException {
    class RethrowableTask implements Runnable {
        private volatile Throwable t;
        public void run() {
            try { r.run(); }
            catch (Throwable t) { this.t = t; }
        }
        void rethrow() {
            if (t != null)
                throw launderThrowable(t);
        }
    }
    RethrowableTask task = new RethrowableTask();
    final Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
    taskThread.start();
    cancelExec.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { taskThread.interrupt(); }
    }, timeout, unit);
    taskThread.join(unit.toMillis(timeout));
    task.rethrow();
}
```

`timedRun` method is used to run task `r` within a time range. This feature can be implemented by `taskThread.join(unit.toMillis(timeout));`. So, **why do we need scheduled `taskThread.interrupt();`?**

Comment: Well, the point of the exercise is to interrupt a thread, not `join()` it.  `join()` won't interrupt a thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This feature can be implemented by taskThread.join(unit.toMillis(timeout));

This isn't true. The time limit of the join just [determines when the joining thread will give up waiting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)). It doesn't affect the thread being limited with a timeout. The scheduled `interrupt` tells the running thread to shut itself down after the timeout has expired. If it weren't there, that thread would continue to consume resources. Presumably the point of the method is to prevent that.

Comment: You are right, but even if we have a scheduled `interrupt`, it is just a request, the running thread might ignore this request and continue running, it will stop if it wants to.

Comment: @JasonLaw True, the thread can ignore the `interrupt` contract. But Java doesn't provide anything better. Sending `interrupt` is certainly better than letting the thread continue with no chance at all that it will terminate early.